# Audio signal processing book suggestions

Tags: audio, reference-request

I want to start learning about audio signal processing but I cannot find a good starting point. Please suggest books or lecture series.

Comment: I think that a general book on signal processing (plus linear algebra and statistics) is a good starting point. If you want to specialize in audio, it depends on your interest. Speech processing? Music? Stage, movie, games, VR...? Machine learning and acoustics would be useful.

Comment: Make sure you get the basics down: Sampling and reconstruction theorem, Fourier Transforms, Convolution.  After that you'll get to think about non-linear and time-variant techniques, but get the LTI down first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can get it:

[Zölzer, Udo (1997). Digital Audio Signal Processing. John Wiley and Sons. ISBN 0-471-97226-6](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/digital-audio-signal-processing_udo-zvlzer_ing-udo-zolzer/2678676/item/6001131/#isbn=0471972266&idiq=6001131)

or

[Orfanidis](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/introduction-to-signal-processing_sophocles-j-orfanidis/740062/item/18633075/?mkwid=%7cdc&pcrid=380921424897&pkw=&pmt=&slid=&plc=&pgrid=86223744708&ptaid=pla-812302609386&gclid=CjwKCAjwgbLzBRBsEiwAXVIygBjlUnd6a9qdru7yNU3IsBUdBiMih8pivAg7osNbLUpHzhCZqD8P4xoCsykQAvD_BwE#isbn=0132091720&idiq=18633075)

might have to buy them used.

is your interest music processing and synthesis?

there are some nice online books.  Look for anything Julius Smith.  But there are others, but i can't remember any names to search for.

Remembered one:

[Davide Rocchesso](https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToSoundProcessing/page/n1/mode/2up)

[here's another link](http://dsp-book.narod.ru/spv.pdf)

another old one:

[Ken Steiglitz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805316841)

Comment: +1 for Orfanidis. Zölzer is also okay, even though the formulas in that book have to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: i knew Orfanidis before he did that book.  he did a sorta generalization to my *"Equivalence"* paper in the '90s.  Knud Christianson did a better one, but Orfanidis was first to do something to nail down the 5th degree of freedom.

Comment: With Orfandis, is there a significant difference between the "Introduction to" book you linked to and another I found: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0070477949/ I can't tell if they're the same with slightly different titles/covers.

Comment: i don't think that they are the same book, @moinudin.

Comment: Phew. Because I was finding that one really difficult. Fortunately I found the introductory one, and I can see its quite different. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My personal favorite, though I don't usually do much audio signal processing, are Julius O. Smith III's *Spectral Audio Signal Processing* and *Physical Audio Signal Processing*. They're available online [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/) and [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/).

A while ago, he made the *Physical* book available in paperback on [Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/Physical-Audio-Signal-Processing-Instruments/dp/0974560723/ref=smi_www_rco2_go_smi_g3905707922?_encoding=UTF8&%2AVersion%2A=1&%2Aentries%2A=0&ie=UTF8).

Answer (score 3):

Many years ago, when I was studying audio DSP in my university, I had to read the following:

Y. You, “Audio Coding: Theory and Applications,” Springer, 2010 [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441917539)

A. Spanias, T. Painter, V. Atti, “Audio Signal Processing and Coding,” Wiley, 2007 [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471791474).

I was very dissapointed by both. Spanias & Painter provide a nice and thorough overview of MP3 coding (but it contains many typos) though. After a couple of years, I read the books by J. O. Smith III, also mentioned by @Peter K. These are indeed excellent textbooks.